# Running R file that has Dependencies From Linux Command Line

Tags: r

Let say that I have a file

`file1.R` and it has a method `getMe()`

Now, I want to run `file2.R` and it makes calls to `getMe()`

Do I need to run

```
R CMD BATCH file1.R
```

before whenever I want to run

`R CMD BATCH file2.R` ?

Or will R some how be able to determine that file2 has a function that is defined in file1.R?

Whats the standard for running a file that has other function dependencies in other files?

Comment: What about a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to source file1.R so that the functions defined there becomes available for others.

```
source('file1.R')
```

You can do this inside your file2.R. Then run simply

```
R CMD BATCH file2.R
```

Comment: Okay thank you I shall try that :) Would you happen to know what happens when you don't source a file but rather run file1.R then file2.R. I noticed that my program appear to never exit and would not automatically terminate leading me to think that it was actually running. I would like to better understand why it exhibited this behavior

Comment: Its just like running two separate processes independent of each other. The second one will never know what functions are defined by first. If the file execution doesn't seem to terminate check what is written inside, cant say without looking at it.

Comment: Also if you do not want to change source. You can open a R repl and do source('file1.R') then source('file2.R')